# right and left eigenvectors of some specific diagonalizable non normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Imagine that you have a complex symmetric matrix $M$ of size $N\times N$ such that $M_{jk}=M_{kj}$.

Now we create a new matrix $M'$ by multiplying every element below the main diagonal of the original matrix $M$ by a fixed real-valued constant $\xi$ so that: $M'_{jk}=\xi M'_{kj}$, where it is assumed that $j>k$. The new matrix $M'$ now is not even normal, so that $M'^{\dagger} M' - M' M'^{\dagger} \ne 0$, and when studying the spectrum of $M'$, one has to use left $v^{(L)}_j$, and right eigenvectors $v^{(R)}_j$. Generally, there is no simple relation between the right, and left eigenvectors for non-normal operators, and one has to simply construct the corresponding transformation matrix to the right-eigenspace from right eigenvectors $S = \left( v^{(R)}_1, \: v^{(R)}_2, \: \ldots \:, v^{(R)}_N \right)$, and then invert it $S^{-1} = \left( v^{(L)}_1, \: v^{(L)}_2, \: \ldots \:, v^{(L)}_N  \right)^{T}$, and the corresponding left eigenvectors are the rows of the obtained $S^{-1}$.

However, I noticed that for $M'$ described above there is a relation $v^{(L)}_j = c_j v^{(R)}_j$, where $c_j$ is some complex-valued constant (which is different for different $j$'s).

Of course, all of the above suggests that $M$, and $M'$ are diagonalizable.

My question is: whether is it possible to somehow mathematically derive the constants $c_j$? And do $c_j$ depend solely on the entries of the corresponding right eigenvector $v^{(R)}_j$ or they might also depend on the entries of other right eigenvectors?

Comment: There is no reason to assume that the original matrix is normal; complex-symmetric matrices need not be normal in general. For example, 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&i\\i&-1}
$$
fails to be normal.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is an easy question to answer in the case that $M$ is [tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), but I don't know if this solution is useful in the more general case.

Comment: Hi, Ben. Yes, I agree that even the original complex-symmetric matrix M is not normal. However, if it is diagonalizable, then by normalizing each right eigenvector such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \left( v^{(R)}_{j,k} \right)^2 = 1$ (not the regular L2-norm with the absolute value), then left eigenvectors are just transposed right eigenvectors. I have found this in some old mathematical article, the name of which I can not recall, but it is easy to test numerically that it works. So, for $M$ the relation between left, and right eigenvectors is simple, while for $M'$ it is just not clear.